# how do i identify files/directories that were added or removed in a git commit?

Tags: git, git-log

I need to write a script that incrementally keeps track of files and directories added and removed from a git repo.

I have tried to use:

```
git log -n1 --pretty="format:" --name-only
```

But that only tells me which files were committed.  It does not specify if it was added or removed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The option you're looking for is `--name-status`. Like `--name-only` it's actually a git-diff option; git-log accepts those to determine how it'll display patches.

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=oneline --name-status
```

Or equivalently (minus the log header):

```
git diff --name-status HEAD^ HEAD
```

As isbadawi points out, you can also use git-whatchanged. This is pretty much git-log with a specific diff output:

```
git whatchanged -n 1
```

You might like the `--name-status` version better, though, since it doesn't show all the blob hashes, just the human-readable statuses.

Comment: That does it!  Now I just have to write a script to read that line and pick out the A's and D's and I'm done.  Thanks.

Comment: Example of outputting the specific commit which contains the **addition** of a file named **.gitignore** in the format of _commit message, names and status of changed files_: `git log --name-status --diff-filter=A --follow .gitignore`

Answer (score 8):

[`git whatchanged`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-whatchanged.html)

Comment: Why was this not voted higher?  Plain English, easy to remember, does the trick.

Comment: @elPastor It wasn't voted higher because it's intended to be deprecated and replaced by `git log`. It is still useful now, but might not be for future readers.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  Although `git log` doesn't include the files added, at least not in its plain form.